# Force to use Autowired with requared=false flag for some interface

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have an interface that can have no implementation loaded to application context . I want all my users know about it. Is there common way to force use of `@Autowired(required=false)` for some specific interface?

Comment: IMO it's not very common to have a missing bean in the context.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want all my users to know". You mean indicate to users at startup about the missing implementation

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I can`t control it. Implementations are loaded in runtime

Comment: @ssedano If someone inject it with required=true flag than code can`t be compiled. Something like this. Is there some tool for that?

Comment: @WojciechFrącz what kind of example can I provide? It`s very abstract trouble. It can be any interface, any bean that implement it, any other bean that inject and use it